# how to replace something by using replace with in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the button `submit` identified by `dvv` with `""`( just to remove the button). So I'm using this code, It works but I should click on the button 'test" twice to work. Any explanation?

```
<script>
    $.fn.gotof = function() { 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btt').click(function(){
                $('#dvv').replaceWith("");
            });
        });
    };

    function dofunc() {
        $.fn.gotof();  
    } 
</script>

<button id="btt" onclick="dofunc()">
    test
</button>
<div id="dvv">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is your requirement? want to delete the button? or replace the button text?

Comment: deleting the button

Comment: why not use [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) ?

Comment: is there a remove() function in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

There is another problem. You add event listener only by first click and on the second click it do your work

You can fix that in that way

```js
function dofunc() {
  $('#dvv').replaceWith("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btt" onclick="dofunc()">test</button>
<div id="dvv"> <input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
```

or that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btt').click(function() {
    $('#dvv').replaceWith("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btt">test</button>
<div id="dvv"> <input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
```

In your case you mixed this two approaches in wrong way

Full jQuery style:

```js
$.fn.gotof = function() {
  $('#dvv').replaceWith("");
};


function dofunc() {
  $("#btt").gotof();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btt" onclick="dofunc()">test</button>
<div id="dvv"> <input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to delete the button, use [**remove**](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method

```
$('#btt').click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click the button, an onclick event handler is added. The second time you click the button an on click event handler is added and the PREVIOUSLY ADDED handler is fired.

Replace all your JavaScript with just this snippet

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btt').click(function(){
        $('#dvv').replaceWith("");
     });
  });
```

Comment: but I need some conditions in the function that's why I'm using that function "dofunc()"